# Eclipse PyDev Debugger: Unable to load existing shared libraries - ImportError: libffi.so.7 / libssl.so.1.1

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

When running pydev debugger on eclipse, it errors out about missing shared libraries namely libffi and libssl, although both are installed

```
>locate libffi.so.7

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7
```

```
"/home/user1/.var/app/org.eclipse.Java/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_10.2.1.202307021217/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
import ctypes
  File "/home/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.11.5/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH to run/debug configurations does not solve the problem
set: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Answer (score 0):

Setting the correct LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the correct solution however, in the environment tab in the run configurations, there are 2 options in the end, default is 'append environment to native environment'

The second option is:
'Replace native environment with specified environment'

Choosing to replace (2nd option), solves the problem and the libraries are loaded correctly

Happy Debugging :)